# how to capture an image of android device screen to PC without using DDMS...?

Tags: java, android, mobile, screenshot

I want to capture the screenshots from the andriod mobile to PC through some code for samsung galaxy connected via USB. I dont want to use DDMS provided by the Andriod SDK. I have to write some code in java to capture the same. Help me if somebody knows about this.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at the code for [Droid@Screen](http://blog.ribomation.com/2010/01/droidscreen/) to see how to pull screenshots off the device using USB. Note that this support is undocumented and still requires the Android SDK to be installed on the host machine.

Comment: Thank u CommonsWare for sharing ur knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Using [monkeyrunner](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/monkeyrunner_concepts.html) and a script like this would do the job.

```
#! /opt/android-sdk-linux_86/tools/monkeyrunner

# Imports the monkeyrunner modules used by this program
from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner, MonkeyDevice
# Connects to the current device, returning a MonkeyDevice object
device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection()
# Takes a screenshot
result = device.takeSnapshot()
# Writes the screenshot to a file
result.writeToFile('/tmp/device.png','png')
```

Comment: i got the code of DDMS.. so i m getting it done by it.. but the problem i m facing now is,  the size of the screen is more.. width is 480 but the height is coming 1536000.. so it is going out of bound..

Answer (score 0):

```
First call this method oncreate();   
 new screenshot().execute();


after create given class:


        class screenshot extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {

                super.onPreExecute();


            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

                Log.e("Screenshot", "Called");

                mView = view.getRootView();
                mView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                b = mView.getDrawingCache();

                String extr = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
                File myPath = new File(extr, getString("myapp")
                        + ".jpg");
                Log.e("My_PatH", "" + myPath);
                if (myPath.exists()) 
                    myPath.delete();
                FileOutputStream fos = null;
                try {
                    fos = new FileOutputStream(myPath);
                    b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
                    fos.flush();
                    fos.close();
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), b,
                            "Screen", "screen");
                    Log.e("Bitmap", "" + b);
                    Log.e("myPath", "" + myPath);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Exception e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(String args) {

            }
        }
```